# facebook php sdk get events from facebook page via graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

1,5 months ago I could make requests to graph api explorer and everything was ok. Suddenly, without changing anything in the code I got this error message when I tried to access the event node of a facebook page in graph api:

> Undefined index: events.

I have this code which works fine:

```
$request1 = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/'.$key.'?fields=name,cover,events');
$response1 = $request1->execute();
$graphObject1 = $response1->getGraphObject()->asArray();
$array1 = json_decode(json_encode($graphObject1),true);
$source = $array1['cover']['source'];
```

I can take the cover photo but when I try this :

```
$request2 = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/'.$key.'/events');
$response2 = $request2->execute();
$graphObject2 = $response2->getGraphObject()->asArray();
$array2 = json_decode(json_encode($graphObject2),true);//$key is the page id
$temp = $array2['data'];
```

I got this error:

> Undefined index: events

please help!!

Comment: Wait what? Are you asking us why you can't use `/events` anymore and you have to use `?fields=name,cover,events`? If that's the question, you should ask Facebook.

Comment: my problem is that i get results when i request the events on graph api explorer but when i try to run my webpage i get this error Undefined index: events.

Comment: You are not accessing any array element with the index `events` in the code you have shown, so the error message can’t come from that part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a version request. Facebook updates it's API on a regular bases. But they let you use the old version if you make a version request. This way you do not have to worry about the API being updated.

Here is a resource from Facebook on how to go about doing that.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions

Comment: I am using php sdk and i can't find how to make version request.Can you help me ? i am a new programmer...

Comment: $request1 = new FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/'.$key.'?fields=name,cover,events',NULL,'v2.1');

v2.1 is an example. Really you need to figure out which version you are using and enter v followed by that version number. It is the last argument in the constructor. So you have to fill in all the arguments before it. That is why I added the NULL in. You can kind of guess versions to see if it works if you are not sure which version you are using.